# Apache directive to not to redirect REQUEST_URI with IF condition

Tags: apache, if-statement, request-uri

The Apache directive is working successfully to redirect the web application URL if it contains "/login" string in REQUEST_URI to the help page. This works with a single directive as below.

```
RedirectMatch 301 "^(.*)" "https://x.y.com/help-url/"
```

However, I wanted to not to redirect to help page if "REQUEST_URI" contains string `login?next=/scm`

I modified/added directive as below however it is not working as expected.

```
<LocationMatch "^/login">
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/scm#">
        #Do nothing
    </If>
    <Else>
        RedirectMatch 301 "^(.*)" "https://x.y.com/help-url/"
    </Else>
</LocationMatch>
```

Comment: You can probably get away checking for query string first `<If "%{QUERY_STRING}  =~ ...` , but I don't remember if nesting If's will work correctly, really nice try though, but reaching this point you will probably get there sooner using mod_rewrite, and a single check for uri instead of two (one in location match and another in the expression condition)

Comment: Thanks ezra, you are right, i tried to use mod_rewrite directives as below

 'RewriteEngine On'
 'RewriteCond %{HTTP:next=/scm} ^$'
 'RewriteRule ^ - [F] # this will redirect to forbidon page'

this will redirect to forbid page , however, i wanted it to go back to dashboard with out looping into login again and again which i am not yet successful. Any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^next=/scm$
RewriteRule ^/login.+?/scm https://x.y.com/help-url/ [R,L]
```

We check if good query string is not sent, in that case we perform the redirection for the path you want to check to the help url.

Note should you need different checks you can add rewriteconds there as necessary

Comment: It works for Public REPO urls where Application doest not ask for login/sso authantication. however when Private repo is requested the Java application ask user to login with addition String "login?next=/scm" in URI. 

It works for my public repo URLs where Application doest not ask for login/SSO authentication.

Public Rep Clone URL : https://git.x.y.com/scm/projectname1/repo1.git
The application will rightly redirect the user to Redirect URL: https://git.x.y.com/projects/projectname1/repos/reposname1/browse
tomorrow i will try to fix it and update. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I tried your method/directives and this part of the location match is fine I added extra \ for "!^next=\/scm$", I am very thankful for your guidance.
i figured it out that the issue i am experiencing is also  due to a second location match
   <LocationMatch ^/scm>
      Satisfy Any
       Allow from all
       AuthType None
       Require all granted
     </LocationMatch>
this must not execute if the login string present in URI.
I tried as below it did not work
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /login/">
<If>
<Else>
.
.
</Else>